error while using ggarrange function to arrange multiple plots
I am trying to use ggarrange function from ggpubr package to plot multiple plot.
But I a getting an error.
Command used are:
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(n_features,level = level_order), y=count, fill=factor(cond))) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge",width=1) 

box <- boxplot(file[,2:6],
        main = "Prediction accuracy",
        xlab = "n_features",
        ylab = "Spearman Correlaton",
        col = c("blue", "red","green","purple","maroon"),
        names = c("50","100","150","200","250"),
        outline = FALSE)


figure <- ggarrange(plot1, plot2,
                    ncol = 1, nrow = 2)


In as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class list into a grob.

Is there any way to solve this. I did see to to solve this error using
My datasets:
dput(z)
structure(list(data = structure(list(cond = c("unique", "shared", 
"unique", "shared", "unique", "shared", "unique", "shared", "unique", 
"shared", "unique", "shared", "unique", "shared", "unique", "shared", 
"unique", "shared", "unique", "shared"), n_features = c("50", 
"50", "100", "100", "150", "150", "200", "200", "250", "250", 
"50", "50", "100", "100", "150", "150", "200", "200", "250", 
"250"), count = c(2, 146, 0, 153, 0, 151, 0, 151, 0, 152, 2, 
146, 0, 153, 0, 151, 0, 151, 0, 152)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L)), layers = list(<environment>, <environment>), scales = <environment>, 
    guides = <environment>, mapping = structure(list(x = ~factor(n_features, 
        level = level_order), y = ~count, fill = ~factor(cond)), class = "uneval"), 
    theme = list(), coordinates = <environment>, facet = <environment>, 
    plot_env = <environment>, layout = <environment>, labels = list(
        x = "n_features", y = "count", fill = "factor(cond)")), class = c("gg", 
"ggplot"))
> dput(box)
list(stats = structure(c(0.075316330016366, 0.326340525110998, 
0.419705792171986, 0.518182175915815, 0.800133955900424, 0.173991596973575, 
0.396813348418443, 0.4850220821865, 0.582205493099969, 0.836958412835947, 
0.181450814392736, 0.465569421250038, 0.576060786455663, 0.676059212178173, 
0.864595344379551, 0.157118494046783, 0.44250164519669, 0.552644319901773, 
0.637812064817378, 0.862976193771966, 0.157118494046783, 0.412269696797752, 
0.510859592503677, 0.616896268334471, 0.853652369842963), dim = c(5L, 
5L)), n = c(134, 134, 134, 134, 134), conf = structure(c(0.393521092887, 
0.445890491456972, 0.459717683804193, 0.510326480568807, 0.547330779937838, 
0.604790792973489, 0.525986164159591, 0.579302475643956, 0.482929863902362, 
0.538789321104992), dim = c(2L, 5L)), out = 0.815623783946268, 
    group = 1, names = c("50", "100", "150", "200", "250"))

I solved this issue by using earlier comments on stackoverflow:
plotlist <- list(z,box)
ggarrange(plotlist = my_plot_list, labels = c('A', 'B'), nrow = 2,ncol = 1)
but still its giving the same error:
2: In as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class list into a grob.

